# How to switch to file location in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

How can I take (example) C:\File1.exe and move it to C:\Temp\ and then take C:\Temp\File2.exe and move where the other file was (C:) on a batch script and then reverse if the script is executed again?

Comment: Take a look at the `copy` command, also `if exist`. In the future, please at least attempt the question before asking here, and include any relevant code you have, in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sorry, if I was being inconvenient, but the whole batch thing is completely new to me. And, yes, I did try before I ask but it was completely beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution.
Save this as a batch (e. g. `swapCopy.bat`) and call it with parameters, like:
`swapCopy.bat "C:\File1.exe" "C:\Temp\File2.exe"`
It'll switch over the files even if filenames and folders are reversed.

```
    if exist "%~dp1%~nx1" (
        if exist "%~dp2%~nx2" (
            move "%~dp1%~nx1" "%~dp2%~nx1"
            move "%~dp2%~nx2" "%~dp1%~nx2"
            goto exit
        )
    )
    if exist "%~dp2%~nx1" (
        if exist "%~dp1%~nx2" (
            move "%~dp2%~nx1" "%~dp1%~nx1"
            move "%~dp1%~nx2" "%~dp2%~nx2"
        )
    )

:exit
```

Comment: Great, thanks man. This is just what I was looking for! If I could give you 100 green check marks I would :)